# Show new div on button click with jquery and hide first div

Tags: jquery, html, css

Can't really understand jQuery so will try my luck here.

What i need - at the start it does show only `CRAZY` div (`CRAZY2` is not visible). When you click `lasit_komentarus` div , whole `CRAZY` div disappears and instead show only `CRAZY2` div.

```
<div class="CRAZY">
    <a href="#"><div class="ienakt"><p>Ienākt</p></div></a>
    <div class="atkape"/>
    <a href="#"><div class="lasit_komentarus"><p>Lasīt komentārus</p></div></a>
</div>

<div class="CRAZY2">
 <p>This show up instead.</p>
</div>
```

Maybe i need to change something here? Cause code working in jfiddle, but not in my .html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.sticky.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).load(function(){
  $(".header_cont").sticky({ topSpacing: 0 });
});

 $('.lasit_komentarus').click(function () {
 $('.CRAZY').hide();
 $('.CRAZY2').show();
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Do you want the button to toggle between divs?

Comment: Read below what we are trying to solve :P Maybe you can help :)

Answer (score 1):

**Important:** You need to close the `div` that contains the class `.atkape` for to have valid html and for the following to work.

Closing based on the `.lasit_komentarus` click:

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/unwnfrhk/4/)

```
 $('.lasit_komentarus').click(function () {
     $('.CRAZY').hide();
     $('.CRAZY2').show();
 });
```

Or if you want a button to close it as your title suggest:

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/unwnfrhk/)

```
   $('button').click(function() {
      $('.CRAZY').hide();
      $('.CRAZY2').show();
    });
```

Comment: I know this works , but this isn't what i was looking for :)

Comment: Then what are you looking for?

Comment: Hmm, i created what i need here. And it's working. https://jsfiddle.net/unwnfrhk/2/ , but it does not work on my .html :O

Comment: yes, i have <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Actually its probably because of the very first thing I said in my answer. You need to close that dive properly with a `</div>` closing tag.

Comment: Here is the fiddle of my full page: https://jsfiddle.net/unwnfrhk/5/ - i'm shocked. It does work on jfiddle, but it doesnt on my pc. I have jquery added.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a div like this:

```
<div />
```

You'll need to close the div. Also, try not to wrap entire div elements with

```
<a></a>
```

If you want to have the entire div clickable, add this in your js:

```
$('.lasit_komentarus').click(function(){
    //do your show() and hide()
});
```

I think what's happening in your code is that you have a conflict between your "a" tag and the jquery click() function. Take out the "a" element.

Comment: Here is the fiddle of my full page: https://jsfiddle.net/unwnfrhk/5/ - i'm shocked. It does work on jfiddle, but it doesnt on my pc. I have jquery added.

Comment: Try clearing your history and cache. Also, depending on which browser, there's part of your html that could be causing problems. You have this line: <p class="hardcore"> and then you put div's and other elements inside this. You shouldn't use the p element like this. Better is another div.